# Does testing for a false statement execute the same statement if TRUE

Tags: php, oop, if-statement

The code block below actually executes when the whole script is run. What is not clear to me is that method `write` only test for the case of `if data is not written to file`. then the Exception should be thrown. It does say that `if $data exist and writeable` then write to it.

```
      public function write($data) {
     if (@!fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n")) {
        throw new Exception('Could not write to the file.');
     }
  }
```

What am used to is this :

```
     if( condition is true ) {

         echo 'Run Code';

      } else {

       echo 'Throw Exception';

      }
```

or something like this

```
public function query($sql) {
        $result  = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
        if(!$result){
            die("Database Query Failed : ". mysql_error());
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

How is this possible ?

Comment: You're testing for the return value of `fwrite`.  It will be called always when `write` is called.

Comment: @danronmoon Can you please explain a little bit more? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) if(expr) `evaluates` the `expr` to its Boolean value.. which means that in your example when calling the `write` function, the `fwrite` function always gets executed and then `if` checkes if it returns a falsy or truthy value..
and from the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) `fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.` hence `@!fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n")` evaluates to true on error, and the exception is thrown

Comment: Does that mean, anytime an `if(expr)` is run, both `TRUE` and `FALSE` conditions executes..such that if expr is TRUE, FALSE does not execute and vice versa?

Comment: @dotman14 what do you mean by both TRUE and FALSE conditions executes? if you put any condition as `expr` in if(expr) it will get executed.. and then if `expr` returns TRUE the if block gets executed and if it returns FALSE the else block gets executed.. that's the normal behaviour in PHP.. even in your second example `$result  = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection); if(!$result)` it's just like assigning a boolean value to $result and then check if it's true with if.. this could be written as in here if you're not going to use $results after..: `if(!mysql_query($sql, $this->connection))`

Comment: But in the first example I gave above it only test for false. There was no where it says that fwrite should execute

Comment: in the first example the `if` tests if fwrite returns false.. and this cannot be done if it's not executed.. I already explained it in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at explaining such kind of things, but let's try :)

I think you misunderstood how a condition works.

Let's use a simple example

```
if($x == 1) {
    echo 'Run Code';
} else {
    echo 'Throw Exception';
}
```

The `if` and what you put inside are independant. A condition is just a statement that returns a boolean, and a `if` just tests a boolean (whatever returned it). So you could transform this example like this :

```
$is_x_equal_to_one = ($x == 1); // $is_x_equal_to_one now contains true or false
if($is_x_equal_to_one) {
    echo 'Run Code';
} else {
    echo 'Throw Exception';
}
```

The `!` operator negates an expression. If it's true, it will return false, and if it's false, it will return true.
So you could revert your condition like this :

```
$is_x_equal_to_one = ($x == 1);
if(!$is_x_equal_to_one) {
    echo 'Throw Exception';
} else {
    echo 'Run Code';
}
```

Now what if you don't need to run any code and you just want to say that "something is broken" if `$x` is not equal to `1` ? The else statement is always optional :

```
$is_x_equal_to_one = ($x == 1);
if(!$is_x_equal_to_one) {
    echo 'Throw Exception';
}
```

`fwrite` not only writes to a file, it also returns `false` if it didn't worked. If it works, it returns a positive integer. And positive integers are evaluated as `true` with PHP.
That means you can use it like that :

```
$is_write_successful = fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n");
if(!$is_write_successful) {
    echo 'Throw Exception';
}
```

And finally, you can shorten this code by removing a useless temporary variable :

```
if(!fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n")) {
    echo 'Throw Exception';
}
```

Comment: So, `if(!fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n")) { echo 'Throw Exception';}` will execute fwrite if `if(!fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n"))` returns false

Comment: @dotman14 No. `fwrite` will be executed anyway. `fwrite` already does the job for you. This function internally does something like `if(file can be written) { [write file]; return [file size]; } else { return false; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the `if` as this:

```
$returnValue = @fwrite($this->_fp, $data . "\n");
if (!$returnValue) {
```

So it will always execute the `fwrite` function.